# window.location.href does not change the URL on button click

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to start of by saying that I have little knowledge of writing code in any form but can read and understand, for the most part.

I am trying to create a Chrome extention that will change part of the URL for the active tab (*effectively a find and replace*), and then load the newly changed URL in the same tab.
So far I have a popup with a separate button that shows up when clicking the extention icon, but I am unable to make this button work. While I have not given up on finding a solution on my own, I come to you for help again as I don't know what I am missing.

Right now nothing happens when clicking the button.

**Code:**

(background.js is empty)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Extention name",
  "description": "Extention description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "Author Name",
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },

  "permissions": ["storage" , "nativeMessaging" , "notifications" , "tabs"],
  "action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html"
 }
}
```

popup.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="Change">Change</button>
    <script src="language.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

language.js: (Courtesy of mplungjan)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let url = new URL(window.location.href);

  const Change = document.getElementById('Change').click();
  const replace = () => {
    console.log(Change.textContent, url.pathname)
    const isEnglish = url.pathname.indexOf('en-US') != -1;
    const from = isEnglish ? 'en-US' : 'nb-NO';
    const to = isEnglish ? 'nb-NO' : 'en-US';
    url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(from, to)
    // window.history.pushState('', '', url);
  };

  Change.addEventListener('click', replace);
  replace();
});
```

Now the line `Change.addEventListener('click', replace);` throws the following error within chrome://extensions/:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function next() {
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_self' )
}


// we used '_self' to open the url int the same tab... If you want to open it in a seperate tab , then you can remove '_self'

/// You can give any url 'https://stackoverflow.com/' is only for an example
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="next()" id="Change">Change</button> <!---YOU CAN GIVE ANY NAME TO THE FUNCTION-->
    <script src="language.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you misunderstood. I am looking to essentially do a "find and replace" function for the URL that is currently displayed for the loaded page.